# Coherence Cache filter | Missing or inaccessible method RuntimeException

Tags: java, caching, filter, oracle-coherence

I am new to Oracle Coherence Cache.

I had configured a Static Distributed cache using the read-write-backing-map-scheme.

I am putting the data in cache

```
CacheFactory.getCache(regionName).put("EntityName",Vector<Entity>);
```

Now I am trying to filter the cached data using `com.tangosol.util.filter.EqualsFilter`:

```
EqualsFilter filter = new EqualsFilter(new ReflectionExtractor("getStateCd", 2);
```

From Cache I am getting the cached data but on passing the filter argument it is throwing exception
i.e.  CacheFactory.getCache(regionName).entrySet(filter);

> RuntimeException: Missing or inaccessible method : java.util.Vector.getStateCd();
>   at com.tangosol.util.extractor.ReflectionExtractor.extract(ReflectionExtractor.java:113)

How can I make Reflection Extractor to look for the getStateCd method in the `Entity` and not the `Vector` as  `Vector<Entity>` or `List<Entity>`?

Comment: Your `EqualsFilter` extractor has a syntax error.  Are you looking values where `vector.get(2).getStateCd()` is equal to some value, or where any/all `entity.getStateCd() == 2`?

Comment: It does not have any syntax error, basically its  fetch all the records from cache where entity.getStateCd() = 2

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to implement `ValueExtractor` interface to collect  `stateCd` field value from every `Entity` into `Collection`. And use this extractor with Coherence `ContainsFilter` or `ContaisAnyFilter`